# Pandas str, int, and float columns concatenation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text1 = ['22211', '1111', np.NaN]
Int1 = ['5555', np.NaN, '4444']
Float1 = [np.NaN, '3333.0', '231.0']
Text2 = ['222115555', '11113333', '4444231']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text1': text1, 'Int1': Int1, 'Float1': Float1})
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'Text1': text1, 'Int1': Int1, 'Float1': Float1, 'Result': Text2})
```

Need to concatenate cols with NaN and different types.

Need help understanding how to do this properly. I run into it over and over again and keep having issues.

I have tried to set each column as a `'str'` when using `pd.read_csv` or `pd.read_excel`

Also tried this from other questions I have seen on here. 
`df = df.fillna("")` (so astype('int') will work)

```
df['Float1'] = df['Float1'].astype('int').astype('str')
```

Get this usually -- `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

The `df['Results']` are usually keys in mapping dictionaries (more cols in df above) for other datasets, so getting them in `str format` is usually best--open to other opinions and spend hours on it.

Just looking for 'How to do this, conceptually and concretely', since I continually run into this when trying to analyze/manipulate data from our legacy excel/csv sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could cast to dtype `str`, `join`, then use `str.replace` to get rid of `'nan'` values. Then perhaps use `str.rstrip` to get rid of the trailing ".0"s:

```
df['Result'] = df.astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1).str.replace('nan','').str.rstrip('.0')
```

Output:

```
   Text1  Int1  Float1     Result
0  22211  5555     NaN  222115555
1   1111   NaN  3333.0   11113333
2    NaN  4444   231.0    4444231
```

Comment: Ok. If the float was not always at the end would I just use a .replace(.0, '')?

Comment: @chasedcribbet in that case, it may be better to strip the `".0"`s on the "Float" column before `join`ing; so like: `df=df.astype(str); df['Float1'] = df['Float1'].str.rstrip('.0')`

Comment: Thank you. If anyone else has a similar issue. If there are other cols in your df, df[['col1', 'col'2, 'col3']].apply(''.join, axis=1) worked as well. Using similar steps from @enke above.